# How to restrict the date and time in Schema?

Tags: xml, schema, xsd-1.0

I have the following element in XML File:

```
<checkinfo checksum="2af4" txtime="04:35pm" txdate="2/17/07" />
```

How can i restrict the values in `XSD` from `txtime` and `txdate`

to accept only values like `03:15:pm and 03/07/2018`

Comment: Do you really have to use these date and time formats? Wouldn't it be better to adopt international standards and use 2018-07-03 and 16:35?

Comment: Yes, because the XML File is given and I need to adapt the XSD Schema with this file..

Comment: I think you (well, someone) has made a bad design decision and you are now paying the cost of the mistake. When that happens, it's best not to dig yourself deeper into the hole.